# Having Custom Authentication and windows authentication in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, windows-authentication

I am having a Api Controller which relies on OWIN token. The Owin is configured in startup.cs

Startup.cs

```
  public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                Provider = new OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider()
                {
                    OnValidateClientAuthentication = async c =>
                    {
                        c.Validated();
                    },
                    OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials = async c =>
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
                            {
                                // validate the credentials
}
}
}
```

Now i want to add a new controller which relies solely  windows authentication.

I am doing this because one of the client is windows app which run on our network. it identify user using windows credentials. so the app does not want to request the user for password.

Please suggest...